# How to create url with parameters in get request laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to create an url as shown below

```
/domain/url=cloud_hosting&name=cloud_hosting
```

this is the href url that I use in my blade

```
<a href="{{ url('domain', ['url' => Request::segment(2), 'name' => $page_name]) }}">continue</a>
```

but that href url is generating different route

```
/domain/cloud_hosting/cloud_hosting
```

I have tried this one:

```
<a href="{{ route('domain') }}?url={{ Request::segment(2) }}&name={{ $page_name }}">Continue</a>
```

and that's working fine. But is there any other way which is nice and beautifull?
Thank you

Comment: is the domain root url?

Comment: `route('domain', [ 'url' => Request::segment(2), 'name' => $page_name ])` might also work

Comment: @NaveedAli. Not, it's just normal route defined on web.php `Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'domain', 'Customer\DomainConfigurationControllers@index');`

Comment: @apokryfos, that's not what I wanted because it will be generating `/domain/cloud_hosting/cloud_hosting`

Comment: do you want to add it as a query string?

Comment: I was under the impression that it would only do that if you had route parameters with that name

Comment: @NaveedAli yes it's query string parameter.

Comment: @apokryfos umm I don't create a route for that so it's error result but if the route is available it will be working but that's not the goal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like below. simply make a get request as in **Web.php**

```
Route::get('domain')
```

and can use it like below and can pass multiple query strings:

```
<a href="{{ url('domain?url='.Request::segment(2).'&name='.$page_name) }}">continue</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [query](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-array-query) method:

```php
url('domain', Arr::query(['url' => request()->segment(2), 'name' => $page_name]))

// /domain/url=cloud_hosting&name=cloud_hosting
```